# Deploying NodeJS App with HTTP2(H2) on Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, https, google-cloud-run, http2, spdy

I am trying to deploy a simple NodeJS application which is HTTP2(H2) enabled, this is working fine locally

Here is my NodeJS code

```
const spdy = require('spdy')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const port = 8080
const CERT_DIR = `${__dirname}/cert`;
const app = express()

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({message: 'Welcome to node HTTP2'})
})
const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(`${CERT_DIR}/server.key`),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(`${CERT_DIR}/server.crt`)
}

spdy
  .createServer(options, app)
  .listen(port, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } else {
      console.log('Listening on port: ' + port + '.')
    }
  })
```

I have created self signed certificate and key using `openssl` command, here is the output in the browser locally

[image]

but after I deploy it to cloud run and enable use HTTP/2 end-to-end as shown below.

[image]

It gives me the below response

[image]

I have checked the logs of cloud run, and the error message says `The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#malformed-response-or-connection-error`

[image]

If you ask me, why am I turning my app into HTTP2, it is because I want to make request of size more than 32MB, which is a limitation of cloud run if you are using HTTP/1 server

[image]

my question is, is it possible to deploy my NodeJS app with HTTP/2 server enabled to cloud run ? if so where exactly have I gone wrong above?

**my curl output of localhost url**

[image]

**my curl output of cloud run url**

[image]

Comment: before you configure it for http/2, have you verified if your service supports h2c requests?

Comment: Have you checked if your Cloud Run service [handles `h2c` requests](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2#before_you_configure) by using this cURL command `curl -i --http2-prior-knowledge http://localhost:[PORT]`?

Comment: Hey @PalakJain, I am not sure if  I understood your question well, once after creating app we can check this in browser's network tab and can see H2 over there, that clearly says my service supports h2c requests. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @UmamaheswararaoMeka as explained by Robert G, refer the page https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2#before_you_configure

Answer (score 1):

I have taken out spdy, express and certs, I have tried using only http2 package.

```
const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require("fs")
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const server = http2.createServer();

server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  const method = headers[':method']
  const path = headers[':path']

  if (method === 'GET' && path === '/') {
    stream.respond({ ':status': 200, 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
    stream.end('Hello, Welcome to HTTP2 Endpoint')
  } else if (method === 'GET' && path === '/users') {
    fs.readFile('users.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error, e.g., file not found
        stream.respond({ ':status': 500, 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
        stream.end('Internal Server Error', err)
        return;
      }
      stream.respond({':status': 200,'content-type': 'application/json',})
      stream.end(data)
    })
  }
  else {
    // Handle other endpoints or return a 404
    stream.respond({ ':status': 404, 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
    stream.end('Not Found')
  }
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

That worked for me, here is my output using curl locally.

[image]

Here is in the browser after deploying it to cloud run

[image]

I am able to make the request for the file which is more than 32MB

[image]

Not sure why chrome is showing `h3` instead of `h2` as protocol, bit it worked for me.

Please correct me if I am wrong here.

The part which I didn't like is writing if else conditions for endpoints. I am not sure if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [using HTTP/2 (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2):

> For Cloud Run services, Cloud Run by default downgrades HTTP/2 requests to HTTP/1 when those requests are sent to the container. If you want to explicitly set your service to use HTTP/2 end-to-end, with no such downgrading, you can configure it for HTTP/2.
>
> Your Cloud Run service must handle requests in [HTTP/2 cleartext](https://http2.github.io/faq/#can-i-implement-http2-without-implementing-http11) (`h2c`) format, because TLS is still terminated automatically by Cloud Run.

To confirm that your service supports `h2c` requests, [test the service locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local) using this cURL command:

```
curl -i --http2-prior-knowledge http://localhost:[PORT]
```

### EDIT:

Since you're using a self-signed certificate and CA wasn't able to verify the legitimacy of the server, there are workarounds that you may perform in order to disable strict certificate checking:

1. You may use the `-k` switch to disable `curl` strict certificate checking.

   ```
   curl -k https://random.com
   ```
2. You may also use `--insecure`, achieving the same result.

   ```
   curl -insecure https://random.com
   ```
3. Or, you can disable SSL certificate validating by writing it to `.curlrc` configuration file.

   ```
   echo insecure >> $HOME/.curlrc
   ```

You may check the documentations below for your reference:

- [Fix “failed to verify the legitimacy of the server” error in cURL](https://linuxpip.org/curl-failed-to-verify-the-legitimacy-of-the-server/)
- [Ignore SSL Certificate Error with cURL](https://linuxhandbook.com/ignore-ssl-certificate-error-curl/)